# How to show that this decision problem is in co-NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, co-np

Given a set of strictly positive numbers $a_1, ..., a_n$, the problem is to determine if $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ different indexes $i_1, ..., i_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ exist so that $$\frac{a_{i_j}}{a_{i_{j-1}}} = \frac{a_{i_{j+1}}}{a_{i_j}}$$ for $2 \leq j \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

How to show that this problem is in co-NP ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any attempts?

Comment: @Evil I tried to find a way to link this problem with the partition problem by summing... without success.

Comment: Unfold the definition. Give an algorithm.

Comment: Slight change: You need [n/2] + 1 indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P is a subset both of NP and of co-NP. Do you think the problem is in P?

(O(n^3) solution is trivial if poster states the problem correctly. As it is, $i_1 = i_2 = i_3  ... = 1$ is a solution.)

You need n/2 different indices $i_j$ such that $a_{i_2} / a_{i_1} = a_{i_3} / a_{i_2}$, $a_{i_3} / a_{i_2} = a_{i_4} / a_{i_3}$, etc.

There are $n^2 - n$ ways to choose $i_1$ and $i_2$. Once you chose these, let $d = a_{i_2} / a_{i_1}$. Then we must have $a_{i_3}$ = $a_{i_2} \cdot d$, $a_{i_4}$ = $a_{i_2} \cdot d^2$, $a_{i_5}$ = $a_{i_2} \cdot d^3$ etc. So all you have to do is check whether there are enough $a_i$ with these values and take their indices.

You can do this faster, but all I cared about was whether it's polynomial time.